# How to make Windows taskbar remember the order of apps?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, taskbar, utility

How to make Windows 10/11 taskbar remember the order of apps from left to right? Even if it is not pinned on taskbar, if you change the opening order next time you boot, you still have to use the remembered order.

For example, let taskbar remember the sequence software A B C D E F G H I J K,
Next time you turn on your Windows computer, open four of the software K A G D,
taskbar must be automatically arranged into A D G K

Comment: In the absence of a better way, the taskbar (for me) is ordered as the Apps start. I think that is what you are seeing. I just click on what I need so order is entirely unimportant

Comment: Unless you start the apps in a particular order, or you pin them and then rearrange them in that order, windows does not support it. I use TidyTabs, to group apps together, and it will then show a small ribbon on the apps that you can click to switch apps. This ribbon does offer a sort based on inclusion rule, so you can order the apps to always show up in a certain order. (off by default)